# FCM push notification not recived on device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/) to make FCM push notification, Its just a empty app, I am trying to send push notification.

I am able get notification locally but not recieving notification sent from firebase console

I have added this line in dependencies section of app build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

I have added these lines in dependencies section of module build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

and at bottom of  of module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here are all the files of app

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mysite.myapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
</application>
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService**

```
package com.mysite.myapp;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("refreshedToken", refreshedToken);            
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
package com.mysite.myapp;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){                
        }

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();   
    }
}
```

**MyNotificationManager**

```
package com.mysite.myapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;    
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    private MyNotificationManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, MyConstants.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);    

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    

        if (mNotifyMgr != null) {
            mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

}
```

**MyConstants**

```
package com.mysite.myapp;

public class MyConstants {    
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "MYAPP Notification";
    public static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "www.mysite.com";
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.mysite.myapp

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(MyConstants.CHANNEL_ID, MyConstants.CHANNEL_NAME, importance)
            mChannel.description = MyConstants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION
            mChannel.enableLights(true)
            mChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
            mChannel.enableVibration(true)
            mChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        }

        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(this).displayNotification("Greetings", "Hello how are you?");


    }

    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object {            
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

Please see why I am not able to receive notification from firebase console and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please let me know that are you testing push when app is in background or foreground ?

Comment: kindly take remoteMessage.getData() instead of remoteMessage.getNotification()  ...

Comment: @AndroidTeam i am testing in both background or foreground

Comment: @SolaimanHossain its showing me this error `error: cannot find symbol method getTitle()` when using `remoteMessage.getData()`

Comment: For background you need to use remoteMessage.getData() and if application is foreground then remoteMessage.getNotification().

Comment: Please check with this link also : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message

Comment: @AndroidTeam I have tried `remoteMessage.getData()` like this `data.get("title").toString();` and `body = data.get("body").toString();` but still not receiving notification in background or foreground